# How to restore Sony Xperia M when asking for password to decrypt storage?

Tags: applications, factory-reset, sony-xperia, hard-reset, flashtool

My sister came up with her phone asking for password to decrypt storage and she said she didn't set any password. I can't put the phone on **USB Debugging** cause i don't have access to phone settings.

I tried to use Sony PC Companion to reinstall Android but it says that was not found any software to the phone.
Also tried to install Android using a using a build by FlashTools but i'm getting an error to write files based on write permissions on phone since it's locked as encrypted.

The Recovery Mode (using power button and volume-up) doesn't work either.

How can i reset to factory settings or even reinstall Android with these conditions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure booting into recovery and wiping `/data` will be your only option then. Unless, however, you somehow get the password.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't boot into recovery mode. It does'n work when using **power button** and **volume-up** or even **volume-down**. I tried so many ways and always boot to the system instead of recovery mode screen.

Comment: Can you try the link given below. [Hardreset Sony Xperia-M](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/sony/sony-xperia-m-c1904/)

Comment: Already tried all of these methods.

Comment: Actually, the phone runs Android Jelly Bean 4.3, but i can install Android Lollipop too.

Comment: i am also facing same problem but i didn't get any solution for that,i given my mobile in sony service centre let's see if i get any solution or not.

Comment: anybody found any solution for this

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.